# Why is my teammate's name flashing on the screen?

Tags: airmech

In a match today, I saw that the name of my teammate was flashing on the side of the screen.  What does this mean?  I assume it is my teammate trying to signal me.  If so, how can I replicate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teammate is trying to signal you to go to their location.  Just fly in the direction of the flashing name to go to where they want you to go.

If you want to do this yourself, you need to use the <kbd>Z</kbd> key.

- **Tap** <kbd>Z</kbd> to request your teammate(s) to go **your location**.
- **Double-tap** <kbd>Z</kbd> to drop a **beacon** and request your teammates to go there.  The dropped beacon model can also be seen by your enemy.

[image: Red Beacon on the Ground]

[Source](http://airmech.wikia.com/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_Do_I_Place_Beacons_Or_Let_My_Team_Know_Where_I_Am.3F)

Comment: Excuse the 3D rendering glitches in the screenshot - my graphics card is broken.